# SSH connection is immediately closed by remote host after successful login

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, openssh

When I am trying to take ssh of a remote network router, the connection closes immediately after successful login. However, if I send command also with ssh login, like ssh user@remote-ip "command", the command is getting executed. After searching for solution, I found that one of the issues could be the lack of shell for the particular user. The shell of the user for which I am trying of ssh is set to /bin/false.

However, I have successfully tried the following ssh clients to connect to the same network router

1. Using paramiko (successfully getting cli shell, from CentOS 7 and Windows machines)
2. Using putty from windows(successfully getting cli shell)
3. using plink from windows (successfully getting cli shell)

Only when using ssh command from CentOS machine, I am not getting the cli shell of remote network router.

Comment: try `ssh -vvv user@host` and check if the output will provide more information.